# Unable to launch logbox because react was unable to create the root view in Google Pixel 8.0

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

APK installed in device but when i open showing error (Only for android 8.1)

```
Device: Google Pixel
Operating System: Android 8.0
Screen size: 5.0 in - 2.5 x 4.4 in
Viewport: 411 x 731 dp
Aspect Ratio: 16 : 9
```

```
07-22 12:57:46.668 E/unknown:ReactNative( 6529): Unable to launch logbox because react was unable to create the root view
```

[Complete log file](https://api.browserstack.com/applive/sessions/7aa6217e3cc328fc4b98b602141a07617e2db00a/devicelogs)

Comment: have you found the fix?

Answer (score -2):

**Solution**

In the root of your application.

Import ignoreWarning.js file present in utils folder (or anywhere) only in dev mode.

```
if (__DEV__) {
  import('./utils/ignoreWarnings');
}
```

Inside utils folder -> `ignoreWarning.js`

```
import {LogBox} from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs([]);
```